# Adding Functionality to Multiple Base Classes in Propel

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a group of model peer classes that should all have the same functions. Rather than copying and pasting to each every time I add a new one to the group, I would rather add the functions to a class the model peer classes extend. Unfortunately, as the model peer classes extend from Base classes such as `BaseModelPeer`, it's not possible.

Propel 1.5 has added a [basePeer](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Schema#tableelement) attribute, which can allow you to set `BaseModelPeer` to extend from a given class. However, by default, a `BaseModelPeer` class does not extend from anything. Instead, it just makes all its calls to the `BasePeer` class, which has different signatures for its functions. By changing the `basePeer` attribute, the `BaseModelPeer` extends from your new class, let's call it `NewBasePeer`, and changes the calls to `BasePeer` to `NewBasePeer`. As the signatures differ, though, this just causes it to fall apart!

I am actually trying to follow on from Symfony's [Zend Lucene tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/17), moving some of the functions which make items indexable to this `NewBasePeer` class. One of these functions is `doDeleteAll`. BaseModelPeer's signature of this function looks like this:

```
public static function doDeleteAll($con = null)
```

But inside this function it makes a call like this:

```
$affectedRows += BasePeer::doDeleteAll(ModelPeer::TABLE_NAME, $con, ModelPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
```

As BaseModelPeer doesn't extend `BasePeer`, it's fine. But by changing the `basePeer` attribute in the schema, the function call changes to:

```
$affectedRows += NewBasePeer::doDeleteAll(ModelPeer::TABLE_NAME, $con, ModelPeer::DATABASE_NAME);
```

`BaseModelPeer` now extends `NewBasePeer`, meaning for it to override the call to `doDeleteAll()`, they need identical signatures. Clearly the `BaseModelPeer` class is now contradicting itself!

Is this a bug with Propel? If not, how is one meant to use the `basePeer` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rather than copying and pasting to each every time I add a new one to the group, I would rather add the functions to a class the model peer classes extend.

The correct way is to define a [Propel Behavior](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/behaviors)